# Python sort a JSON list by two key values

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have a JSON list looks like this:

```
[{ "id": "1", "score": "100" },
{ "id": "3", "score": "89" },
{ "id": "1", "score": "99" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "100" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "59" }, 
{ "id": "3", "score": "22" }]
```

I want to sort the id first, I used

```
sorted_list = sorted(json_list, key=lambda k: int(k['id']), reverse = False)
```

This will only sort the list by id, but base on id, I also want sort the score as will, the final list I want is like this:

```
[{ "id": "1", "score": "100" },
{ "id": "1", "score": "99" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "100" },
{ "id": "2", "score": "59" },
{ "id": "3", "score": "89" }, 
{ "id": "3", "score": "22" }]
```

So for each id, sort their score as well. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a tuple adding second sort key `-int(k["score"])` to reverse the order when breaking ties and remove `reverse=True`:

```
sorted_list = sorted(json_list, key=lambda k: (int(k['id']),-int(k["score"])))

[{'score': '100', 'id': '1'}, 
 {'score': '99', 'id': '1'}, 
 {'score': '100', 'id': '2'}, 
 {'score': '59', 'id': '2'},
 {'score': '89', 'id': '3'}, 
 {'score': '22', 'id': '3'}]
```

So we primarily sort by `id` from lowest-highest but we break ties using `score` from highest-lowest. dicts are also unordered so there is no way to put id before score when you print without maybe using an OrderedDict.

Or use pprint:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(sorted_list)

[{'id': '1', 'score': '100'},
 {'id': '1', 'score': '99'},
 {'id': '2', 'score': '100'},
 {'id': '2', 'score': '59'},
 {'id': '3', 'score': '89'},
 {'id': '3', 'score': '22'}]
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, i don't think you will get the correct output though, the OP wants to sort from lowest to highest id but break ties  with highest to lowest score

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, i should be x but it still wont work, you cannot sort string digits without casting to int and in this case the OP wants to sort both ways so it is not a straightforward sort

Comment: Good answer. You could print out the id before the score without using `OrderedDict` with something like `'{{ "id": "{id}", "score": "{score}" }}'.format(**dct)` for each dictionary in the sorted list.