# Python sorting json list by 2 key values of different types

Tags: python, json

I've been following this answer:
[Python sort a JSON list by two key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491289/python-sort-a-json-list-by-two-key-values)

I want to adapt this to my case:

```
[
    {'score': 0.1, 'id': 1, 'flag': true}, 
    {'score': 0.234, 'id': 2, 'flag': false}, 
    {'score': 0.4, 'id': 3, 'flag': false}
]
```

I need a sorting by flag(boolean) and score(float) kind of like the ones you do in SQL. 
In this case the result would be:

```
[
    {'score': 0.1, 'id': 1, 'flag': true}, // first because the flag is true
    {'score': 0.4, 'id': 3, 'flag': false} //second because the score is higher 
    {'score': 0.234, 'id': 2, 'flag': false}, 

]
```

I am trying to use

```
sorted_result = sorted(json, key=lambda k: (bool(k['flag']), -float(k['score'])))
```

but it doesn't sort as expected

Comment: The question you refer to seems to give you all the information you need. But for completeness you should update your question with the actual output your code produces,

Comment: Well it doesn't cover bool and float flags in combination. And the sorted result is just not there!

Comment: You need to provide two sorting keys i.e `flag, score`

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sort a JSON list by two key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491289/python-sort-a-json-list-by-two-key-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just negate `flag` as well:

```
>>> data = [{'score': 0.1, 'id': 1, 'flag': True}, 
            {'score': 0.234, 'id': 2, 'flag': False}, 
            {'score': 0.4, 'id': 3, 'flag': False}]

>>> sorted(data, key = lambda k: (-k['flag'], -k['score']))
[{'score': 0.1, 'id': 1, 'flag': True}, {'score': 0.4, 'id': 3, 'flag': False}, {'score': 0.234, 'id': 2, 'flag': False}]
```

You also don't need to typecast `bool()` and `float()` here, since the types are already inferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function that returns a tuple as the sorting key.  You can also use `reverse=True` instead of negating the values to sort in descending order: True before False and large to small values.

```
j = [
    {'score': 0.1, 'id': 1, 'flag': True},
    {'score': 0.234, 'id': 2, 'flag': False},
    {'score': 0.4, 'id': 3, 'flag': False}
]

sorted(j, key=lambda x: (x.get('flag'), x.get('score')), reverse=True)
# returns:
[{'flag': True, 'id': 1, 'score': 0.1},
 {'flag': False, 'id': 3, 'score': 0.4},
 {'flag': False, 'id': 2, 'score': 0.234}]
```

If you are loading the json from a string use:

```
import json
j = json.loads('''[
    {"score": 0.1, "id": 1, "flag": true}, 
    {"score": 0.234, "id": 2, "flag": false}, 
    {"score": 0.4, "id": 3, "flag": false}
]''')
```

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do it.  I feel this is cleaner than carrying around negations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sort one value that is int/float in ascending and if there is a tie, sort another value that is string in ascending, here you go :D:

```
arr = [{'score': 10, 'name': 'Helen'},{'score': 10, 'name': 'Zed'},{'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'score': 15, 'name':'Susan'}, {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]
arr

[{'score': 10, 'name': 'Helen'},
 {'score': 10, 'name': 'Zed'},
 {'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'score': 15, 'name': 'Susan'},
 {'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'}]

sorted(arr, key = lambda k: (k['score'], k['name']))

[{'score': 1, 'name': 'Skippy'},
 {'score': 10, 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'score': 10, 'name': 'Helen'},
 {'score': 10, 'name': 'Zed'},
 {'score': 15, 'name': 'Susan'}]
```